# Particle collision in Unity

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I want to count the number of particles (yellow balls) that hit the cube. When a particle hits the cube object, it must disappear.

[image: The particles should be able to collide with my cube object.]

This script is attached to the particle system:

```
    int P_ball = 0;

    void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other) {
       if (other.CompareTag("cube"))
       {
           P_ball = P_ball + 1;
           Debug.Log("Particles : " + P_ball );
       }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Could you edit your question and re upload the image to stack's imgur account by using the 'Image' tool from the edit toolbar? This would prevent link rot in case postimg decides to remove the image!

Comment: Also please describe what actual problem you have with this code. e.g.: what is happening (error messages if you get any), what you expected to happen, ...

Comment: about the image, the sit not accept this type(png) of image !! /-/ my problem i can't count the number of particles hit the cube.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *" i can't count the number of particles hit the cube"*? Is the function not triggered? Or does the comparison fail?

Comment: Also did you enable `Send Collision Messages` in the Inspector, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnParticleCollision.html)?

Comment: Particle system trigger is checked. also the collision messages enabled.

Comment: Actually, looking closer at that screenshot - are you using a 2D collider on the Cube? Or is it at 3D one? (And is the `OnParticleCollision` method called or not? Try putting a `Debug.Log` before the comparison if you are not sure)

Comment: Wait, so, your "Debug.Log("Particles : " + P_ball );" isn't reached, right? Are you sure you have derived the class from MonoBehaviour?

Comment: The documents say something like: "The message is only sent if you enable sendCollisionMessage in the Inspector of the WorldParticleCollider." Did you try that too?